# How does Google, Facebook etc. deal with memory corruption etc

Tags: hardware, memory-corruption

I was wondering how Google, Facebook etc. deal with hardware errors like memory corruptions, calculating errors in the CPU etc. Given the increasing density (and shrinking size) of circuits, it seems the frequency of hardware errors are going up, not down. Also, big providers like Google and Facebook have so many machines that memory corruption must be an everyday occurrence. So I am wondering what kind pf policy they have with regards to this. After all, most algorithms assume that the underlying hardware is operating correctly and that data doesnt change in memory etc. If it does, all bets are essentially off. This could cause corruption not just for the specific data being affected by the error, but it could conceivably spread to other computations. For instance if the error affects a locking/synchronization protocol it could cause data hazards with threads or nodes etc. Or could corrupt a database, causing violations of invariants assumed elsewhere etc. This could cause other nodes, who discover the corruption, to fail. I have seen this in practice where erroneous data in a database (an invalid timestamp in a configuration-related row) caused a whole system to fail because the application validated the timestamp whenever reading the row!

Hopefully, most of the time the errors will simply result in a node crashing etc. maybe even before committing any data (for instance, if an operating system structure is corrupted). But since the errors occur essentially at random, it could occur everywhere and the error could live on without being noticed.

It must be somewhat challenging. Also, I am thinking that big providers must occationally see errors / stack traces in their logs, that cannot be explained through code inspection/analysis, because the situation simply cant happen if the code had executed "as written". But this can often be quite hard to conclude, so it could be a lot of investigation is being spent on an error before it is finally concluded that it must have been a hardware error.

Of course this is not limited to big service providers, since these errors can occur everywhere. But big service providers are much more exposed to it, and it would make sense for them to have a policy in this area.

I can see different ways how it can be addressed:

1) Pragmatic, repair errors as you go along. Often the repair is simply to reboot a machine. In cases where customer data is corrupted and someone complains, then fix that.

2) Hardening of code running on individual nodes. I dont know what techniques could be used, but for instance calculating certain results twice and comparing before committing. This will of course incur an overhead, and also the comparison logic can itself be subject to corruption, but maybe quite low risk since it requires an error in that area specifically. Also, this logic could also be duplicated.

3) Different nodes running in lock-step, comparisons being done between nodes before results are allowed to be committed.

4) Large-scale architectural initiatives to reduce damage from a localized error. Making sure to compare DB content with previous backup(s) to detect bit rot (before blindly making another backup of the current data) etc. Various integrity checks in place. Resiliency in other nodes in case of corrupted data (not relying too strongly on invariants holding etc.). Essentially "being liberal in what you accept".

There might be other things I havent thought of, which is my reason for asking the question :)

Answer (score 0):

At least the memory content must be reliable:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory

There are also other error detection/correction codes used at various levels (checksums, hashes, etc.).

Comment: Hi, yes I think ECC memory is a good thing and sad that it isnt easily available to normal consumers. But still, what about errors occurring before the data is committed to memory (and the checksum calculated), or after it has been read (and the checksum verified). Such errors will not be caught. I suppose also internal memory structures in the CPU (register file etc.) is potentially subject to corruption.

Comment: Also, I thought Google/Facebook tried to use cheap commodity hardware. At least with Intel you have to buy relatively high-end in order for the CPU to even support ECC.

Comment: Network protocols have their own protections. Internal computer buses have their own protections. Harddisks have their own protections. So the remaining vulnerable components are RAM where ECC can help, and CPU where the same problem must be solved soon.